Python test passing in CMake but not with pytest
 def test_cover_fail(self):
    self.url = self._api("cover")
    fo.dis.cover().AndRaise(http_server.RpcError("error"))    
    self.mock.ReplayAll()
    try:
      json.load(self._make_request())
    except (urllib.error.HTTPError, urllib.error.URLError) as e:
      self.assertTrue("error" in e.read())
    except Exception as e:
      self.fail("cover shouldn't fail with exception: %s" % e)
    else:
      self.fail("cover should fail: %s" % e.read())
    self.mock.VerifyAll()

this method was passing in CMakeTest but after integrating with python it is failing with error-  #{'error': {'message': "TypeError('Object of type RpcError is not JSON serializable')", 'details': {}, 'session_id': None}}
How do I alter the code to get the error string in e.read()
